# How can I achieve a consistent design across multiple devices in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-constraintlayout, android-jetpack

I am working on a Jetpack Compose project and trying to achieve a pixel-perfect design based on a Sketch app design. However, when I run the app on two different devices, a Pixel 6 Pro and an Infix Mobility device, the output looks completely different. On the Infix device, there are issues with buttons overflowing on another layout.

[image]

**Here is my code**

```
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Blue)
) {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .weight(1f)
            .padding(30.dp)
    ) {
        val (backImg, headerTextId, subHeaderTextId, profileImageId, txtAddProfilePicId, firstNameId, lastNameId, phoneNumberId, nextBtnId) = createRefs()

        Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img_back),
            contentDescription = "Back",
            modifier = Modifier
                .clickable {}
                .constrainAs(backImg) {
                    top.linkTo(parent.top)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                })

        Column(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(headerTextId) {
            top.linkTo(backImg.bottom, margin = 10.dp)
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
        }) {

            CommonHeaderText(
                text = stringResource(id = R.string.complete_profile), textSize = 26.sp
            )

        }

        Column(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(subHeaderTextId) {
            top.linkTo(headerTextId.bottom)
            start.linkTo(parent.start)
        }) {
            CommonSubHeaderText(stringResource(id = R.string.complete_profile_desc))
        }

        AsyncImage(model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(
            R.drawable.camera_round
        ).crossfade(true).build(),
            contentDescription = "Profile Image",
            placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.camera_round),
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(profileImageId) {
                    top.linkTo(subHeaderTextId.bottom, margin = 15.dp)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                }
                .clip(CircleShape)
                .size(100.dp)
                .clickable {},
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )

        Text(
            stringResource(id = R.string.add_profile_pic),
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(vertical = 5.dp)
                .constrainAs(txtAddProfilePicId) {
                    top.linkTo(profileImageId.top)
                    bottom.linkTo(profileImageId.bottom)
                    start.linkTo(profileImageId.end, margin = 15.dp)
                },
            fontSize = 16.sp,
            color = Color.White,
            fontFamily = avenirFamily,
            fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
        )


        OutlinedTextField(keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Words, imeAction = ImeAction.Next
        ),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp),
            isError = false,
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            placeholder = {
                EditTextPlaceHolder(
                    stringResource(id = R.string.first_name), TextGreenColor
                )
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(firstNameId) {
                    top.linkTo(profileImageId.bottom, margin = 30.dp)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp)),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                errorIndicatorColor = Red,
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                cursorColor = ScreenBackgroundColor,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                focusedLabelColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            singleLine = true,
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.7f),
                fontFamily = avenirFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
            ))

        OutlinedTextField(keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
            capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Words, imeAction = ImeAction.Next
        ),
            isError = false,
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp),
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            placeholder = {
                EditTextPlaceHolder(stringResource(id = R.string.last_name), TextGreenColor)
            },
            modifier = Modifier
                .constrainAs(lastNameId) {
                    top.linkTo(firstNameId.bottom, margin = 20.dp)
                    start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    end.linkTo(parent.end)
                }
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp)),
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                errorIndicatorColor = Red,
                backgroundColor = Color.White,
                cursorColor = ScreenBackgroundColor,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                focusedLabelColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            singleLine = true,
            textStyle = TextStyle(
                fontSize = 16.sp,
                color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.7f),
                fontFamily = avenirFamily,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
            ))

        Column(modifier = Modifier
            .constrainAs(phoneNumberId) {
                top.linkTo(lastNameId.bottom, margin = 20.dp)
                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                end.linkTo(parent.end)
            }
            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp))
            .background(Color.White)) {
            MaterialCountryCodePicker(
                pickedCountry = {

                },
                showErrorText = false,
                showCountryCodeInDIalog = true,
                showDropDownAfterFlag = false,
                textFieldShapeCornerRadiusInPercentage = 10,
                searchFieldShapeCornerRadiusInPercentage = 20,
                countryItemBgShape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
                focusedBorderColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Transparent,
                cursorColor = ScreenBackgroundColor,
                showCountryFlag = false,
                showCountryCode = true,
                countrytextstyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                ),
                countrycodetextstyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                ),
                phonenumbertextstyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                ),
                phonehintnumbertextstyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = TextGreenColor,
                    fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                ),
                searchFieldTextStyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                ),
                dialogcountrycodetextstyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                ),
                searchFieldPlaceHolderTextStyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 16.sp,
                    color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
                    fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                ),
                appbartitleStyle = TextStyle(
                    fontSize = 18.sp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                    fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                    fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
                ),
                defaultCountry = CountryData("+91"),
                onValueChange = {

                },
                text = ""
            )
        }
    }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .weight(0.35f)
            .padding(horizontal = 40.dp)
    ) {
        CommonShadowButton(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.next), backgroundColor = Color.White
        ) {

        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why the output is different on different devices and how to achieve a consistent design across multiple devices in Jetpack Compose?"

**EDIT 1 :**

I am using weight because I have one button which will be placed on fix position on every screen. If i'm using it directly then button will be not placed on same place in every screen that's why i'm using weight.
Let me share you output i want for different screen

[image]

That's why I'm using column weight and placed this function on every screen.

```
   Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .weight(0.35f)
            .padding(horizontal = 40.dp)
    ) {
        CommonShadowButton(
            text = stringResource(id = R.string.next), backgroundColor = Color.White
        ) {

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste the below code and try it .. actually what i did here , removed the weight property and added space between in column property.

```
     Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .background(Blue)
            ) {
                ConstraintLayout(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(30.dp)
.verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())
                ) {
                    val (backImg, headerTextId, subHeaderTextId, profileImageId, txtAddProfilePicId, firstNameId, lastNameId, phoneNumberId, nextBtnId) = createRefs()
            
                    Image(painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.img_back),
                        contentDescription = "Back",
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .clickable {}
                            .constrainAs(backImg) {
                                top.linkTo(parent.top)
                                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                            })
            
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(headerTextId) {
                        top.linkTo(backImg.bottom, margin = 10.dp)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    }) {
            
                        CommonHeaderText(
                            text = stringResource(id = R.string.complete_profile), textSize = 26.sp
                        )
            
                    }
            
                    Column(modifier = Modifier.constrainAs(subHeaderTextId) {
                        top.linkTo(headerTextId.bottom)
                        start.linkTo(parent.start)
                    }) {
                        CommonSubHeaderText(stringResource(id = R.string.complete_profile_desc))
                    }
            
                    AsyncImage(model = ImageRequest.Builder(LocalContext.current).data(
                        R.drawable.camera_round
                    ).crossfade(true).build(),
                        contentDescription = "Profile Image",
                        placeholder = painterResource(id = R.drawable.camera_round),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .constrainAs(profileImageId) {
                                top.linkTo(subHeaderTextId.bottom, margin = 15.dp)
                                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                            }
                            .clip(CircleShape)
                            .size(100.dp)
                            .clickable {},
                        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
                    )
            
                    Text(
                        stringResource(id = R.string.add_profile_pic),
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(vertical = 5.dp)
                            .constrainAs(txtAddProfilePicId) {
                                top.linkTo(profileImageId.top)
                                bottom.linkTo(profileImageId.bottom)
                                start.linkTo(profileImageId.end, margin = 15.dp)
                            },
                        fontSize = 16.sp,
                        color = Color.White,
                        fontFamily = avenirFamily,
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
                    )
            
            
                    OutlinedTextField(keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Words, imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                    ),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp),
                        isError = false,
                        value = "",
                        onValueChange = {},
                        placeholder = {
                            EditTextPlaceHolder(
                                stringResource(id = R.string.first_name), TextGreenColor
                            )
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .constrainAs(firstNameId) {
                                top.linkTo(profileImageId.bottom, margin = 30.dp)
                                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                            }
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp)),
                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                            errorIndicatorColor = Red,
                            backgroundColor = Color.White,
                            cursorColor = ScreenBackgroundColor,
                            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            focusedLabelColor = Color.Transparent
                        ),
                        singleLine = true,
                        textStyle = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.7f),
                            fontFamily = avenirFamily,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                        ))
            
                    OutlinedTextField(keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(
                        capitalization = KeyboardCapitalization.Words, imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                    ),
                        isError = false,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp),
                        value = "",
                        onValueChange = {},
                        placeholder = {
                            EditTextPlaceHolder(stringResource(id = R.string.last_name), TextGreenColor)
                        },
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .constrainAs(lastNameId) {
                                top.linkTo(firstNameId.bottom, margin = 20.dp)
                                start.linkTo(parent.start)
                                end.linkTo(parent.end)
                            }
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp)),
                        colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                            errorIndicatorColor = Red,
                            backgroundColor = Color.White,
                            cursorColor = ScreenBackgroundColor,
                            focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                            focusedLabelColor = Color.Transparent
                        ),
                        singleLine = true,
                        textStyle = TextStyle(
                            fontSize = 16.sp,
                            color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.7f),
                            fontFamily = avenirFamily,
                            fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                        ))
            
                    Column(modifier = Modifier
                        .constrainAs(phoneNumberId) {
                            top.linkTo(lastNameId.bottom, margin = 20.dp)
                            start.linkTo(parent.start)
                            end.linkTo(parent.end)
                        }
                        .clip(shape = RoundedCornerShape(7.dp))
                        .background(Color.White)) {
                        MaterialCountryCodePicker(
                            pickedCountry = {
            
                            },
                            showErrorText = false,
                            showCountryCodeInDIalog = true,
                            showDropDownAfterFlag = false,
                            textFieldShapeCornerRadiusInPercentage = 10,
                            searchFieldShapeCornerRadiusInPercentage = 20,
                            countryItemBgShape = RoundedCornerShape(12.dp),
                            focusedBorderColor = Color.Transparent,
                            unfocusedBorderColor = Color.Transparent,
                            cursorColor = ScreenBackgroundColor,
                            showCountryFlag = false,
                            showCountryCode = true,
                            countrytextstyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                color = Color.Black,
                                fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            ),
                            countrycodetextstyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                color = Color.Black,
                                fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            ),
                            phonenumbertextstyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                color = Color.Black,
                                fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            ),
                            phonehintnumbertextstyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                color = TextGreenColor,
                                fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            ),
                            searchFieldTextStyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                color = Color.Black,
                                fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            ),
                            dialogcountrycodetextstyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                color = Color.Black,
                                fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            ),
                            searchFieldPlaceHolderTextStyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 16.sp,
                                color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.5f),
                                fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Medium
                            ),
                            appbartitleStyle = TextStyle(
                                fontSize = 18.sp,
                                color = Color.Black,
                                fontFamily = poppinsFamily,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
                            ),
                            defaultCountry = CountryData("+91"),
                            onValueChange = {
            
                            },
                            text = ""
                        )
                    }
                }
            
                Column(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(20)
    .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                ) {
                    CommonShadowButton(
                        text = stringResource(id = R.string.next), backgroundColor = Color.White
                    ) {
            
                    }
                }
            }
```

**Note :-**. you have to work on your code quality. if the things are repeating make it common and also use column, row and box when your layout are not complex. Constraints layout is for complex layout.

Comment: It's working like charm, but there is an issue if i remove weight

Comment: can u please refer my updated question

Comment: i updated my answer, i used box which will fixed button at the end